# Python dataframe class __init__ weird behaviour

Tags: python, dataframe, class, initialization

So I'm trying to restructure files in my project and created a following class

File: merge.py

```
class DataFrame:
def __init__(self):
    self.df = pd.DataFrame()
```

in other file I'm calling it

File:merge_files.py

```
from merge import Dataframe
dfx = DataFrame()
```

here's the output for:

```
print(dfx)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<merge.DataFrame object at 0x81503d790>
```

and if I print following:

```
print(dfx.df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

I searched for hours and found no answer. Can someone explain this and propose how to get to empty dataframe using just **dfx** instead of **dfx.df**

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I end up modifying Michael's code so one method performs two tasks, see code below

```
class NewDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
def __init__(self,df: pd.DataFrame):
    super().__init__(df)
```

Example of call:

```
1. df = NewDataFrame(None)
2. df = NewDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(columns=constant.COLUMNS_REPORT))
3. df = NewDataFrame(df_something)
```

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

What your code currently does is create a generic object that has the field df that stores a pandas DataFrame. So the empty datafrrame is a field of the object, but not the object itself.

Instead, you want to inherit the pandas DataFrame class so that when you instantiate your DataFrame class, it's also a pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
print(MyDataFrame())
```

Comment: That worked. So following that logic, I would like to create next class, like this

`class ReadDataFrame(): `
`   def __init__(self,filepath):`
`        self.filepath = filepath`
`       self.df = pd.read_excel(filepath, dtype=str)`

but again run into a problem of accessing an object **dfa** rather than field **df** --> `print(dfa.df)`

Started reading about super(). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `class ReadDataFrame():`
 
`def __init__(self,filepath):` 

`self.filepath = filepath` 

`self.df = pd.read_excel(filepath, dtype=str)`

Comment: Same issue as before, essentially. I suggest you read up on constructors and class inheritance. You have to know a little bit about how the inherited class's constructor works, but in this case, I think `super().__init__(pd.read_excel(filepath, dtype = str))` might work.